# Troubles when trying to build and sign a transaction with web3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, solidity, web3py

I'm watching the tutorial of freeCodeCamp.org,
Solidity, Blockchain, and Smart Contract Course – Beginner to Expert Python Tutorial ([link of the video course)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M576WGiDBdQ&t=14242s) and I'm stucked at ***04:06:47*** because when I try to build a transaction and sign it, my compiler gives me back a lot of errors:

> INFORMAZIONI: impossibile trovare file corrispondenti ai  criteri di
> ricerca indicati. Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\giuse\OneDrive\Desktop\Sol\web3_py_simple_storage\deploy.py",
> line 44, in 
> transaction = SimpleStorage.constructor().buildTransaction(   File "C:\Users\giuse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\eth_utils\decorators.py",
> line 18, in _wrapper
> return self.method(obj, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\giuse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\contract.py",
> line 684, in buildTransaction
> return fill_transaction_defaults(self.web3, built_transaction)   File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 250, in
> cytoolz.functoolz.curry.**call**
> return self.func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\giuse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3_utils\transactions.py",
> line 121, in fill_transaction_defaults
> default_val = default_getter(web3, transaction)   File "C:\Users\giuse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3_utils\transactions.py",
> line 67, in 
> 'gas': lambda web3, tx: web3.eth.estimate_gas(tx),   File "C:\Users\giuse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\eth.py",
> line 759, in estimate_gas
> return self._estimate_gas(transaction, block_identifier)   File "C:\Users\giuse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\module.py",
> line 57, in caller
> result = w3.manager.request_blocking(method_str,   File "C:\Users\giuse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py",
> line 197, in request_blocking
> response = self._make_request(method, params)   File "C:\Users\giuse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py",
> line 150, in _make_request
> return request_func(method, params)   File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.**call**
> return self.func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\giuse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py",
> line 76, in apply_formatters
> response = make_request(method, params)   File "C:\Users\giuse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\gas_price_strategy.py",
> line 90, in middleware
> return make_request(method, params)   File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.**call**
> return self.func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\giuse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py",
> line 74, in apply_formatters
> response = make_request(method, formatted_params)   File "C:\Users\giuse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\attrdict.py",
> line 33, in middleware
> response = make_request(method, params)   File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.**call**
> return self.func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\giuse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py",
> line 74, in apply_formatters
> response = make_request(method, formatted_params)   File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.**call**
> return self.func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\giuse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py",
> line 73, in apply_formatters
> formatted_params = formatter(params)   File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 503, in
> cytoolz.functoolz.Compose.**call**
> ret = PyObject_Call(self.first, args, kwargs)   File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.**call**
> return self.func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\giuse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\eth_utils\decorators.py",
> line 91, in wrapper
> return ReturnType(result)  # type: ignore   File "C:\Users\giuse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\eth_utils\applicators.py",
> line 22, in apply_formatter_at_index
> yield formatter(item)   File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.**call**
> return self.func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\giuse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\eth_utils\functional.py",
> line 45, in inner
> return callback(fn(*args, **kwargs))   File "C:\Users\giuse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\eth_utils\applicators.py",
> line 84, in apply_formatters_to_dict
> yield key, formatterskey   File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.**call**
> return self.func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\giuse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\eth_utils\applicators.py",
> line 72, in apply_formatter_if
> return formatter(value)   File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.**call**
> return self.func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\giuse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\validation.py",
> line 57, in validate_chain_id
> raise ValidationError( web3.exceptions.ValidationError: The transaction declared chain ID 5777, but the connected node is on 1337

I first searched on internet for solutions, but the only one was to add in the transation build one more parameter (the one of the gasPrice), but it didn't solve my problems.

I hope someone can help me, here is the full code I wrote:

```
from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc
import json
from web3 import Web3
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

load_dotenv()
install_solc("0.6.0")

with open("./simpleStorage.sol", "r") as file:
    simple_storage_file = file.read()

compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "Solidity",
        "sources": {"simpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
        "settings": {
            "outputSelection": {
                "*": {"*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.sourceMap"]}
            }
        },
    },
    solc_version="0.6.0",
)

with open("compiledCode.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(compiled_sol, file)

bytecode = compiled_sol["contracts"]["simpleStorage.sol"]["SimpleStorage"]["evm"][
    "bytecode"
]["object"]

abi = compiled_sol["contracts"]["simpleStorage.sol"]["SimpleStorage"]["abi"]

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545"))
chain_id = 5777
my_address = "0xd8BADAe3766759e7e298931dF01F452616dc6dde"
pvt_key = os.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY")

SimpleStorage = w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, bytecode=bytecode)

nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(my_address)

transaction = SimpleStorage.constructor().buildTransaction(
    {
        "chainId": chain_id,
        "gasPrice": w3.eth.gas_price,
        "from": my_address,
        "nonce": nonce,
    },
)

signed_txn = w3.eth.sign_transaction(transaction, private_key=pvt_key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `chain_id = 5777` to `chain_id = 1337`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I did, but the errors are more than before, in fact i can't paste here all of them

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ganache quickstart, instead use New Workspace option so you can save it.

Go to settings on top right corner (If you are using GUI from tutorial video)

Go to server tab and select following values and save.

[image]

Change values accordingly in your code.

Also change create trasaction code to this

```
transaction = SimpleStorage.constructor().buildTransaction(
    {
        "chainId": chain_id,
        "gasPrice": w3.eth.gas_price,
        "from": my_address,
        "nonce": nonce,
    }
)
```

Doing these 2 steps should fix your problem. I just did it for myself.